# A simple question about the definition of martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

The definition of Martingale denotes that $E(M_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=M_n$. This implies $E(E(M_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n))=E(M_n)$. Then does it mean that $E(M_{n+1})=E(M_n)$ using the tower property? If so, what gives a significance to the optional stopping theorem that tells us $E(M_T)=E(M_0)$?

Answer (score 1):

While it is correct that $E(M_n) = E(M_0)$ for all $n$, stating $E(M_T) = E(M_0)$ is pretty different as $T$ is *itself* a random variable so $M_T$ is *not* equal to any of the $M_n$'s (as a random variable).

To see that the "almost-surely boundedness" hypothesis is crucial in this theorem, consider a one-dimensional integer random walk $X$.

Then, you can decide to stop the walk at time $T$ whenever you reach a certain value $B \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed in advance. Then, the occurrence of $T \leq t$ only depends on $X_0, \cdots, X_t$, so $T$ is a stopping time.

Thus, you clearly have $E(X_T) = B$, while $E(X_n)=E(X_0)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks but it is still bugging me that $T\in n$, that T must be some n. Any more help?

Comment: Well $T$ must be some $n$ of course, but the fact that it depends on what you observe about the $M_n$ makes $M_T$ kinda "biased".

You can easily see that intuitively, "value of my martingale at time $n$" with $n$ fixed in advance and "value of my martingale when <*insert condition on past here*>" are not the same.

Comment: In other words, let's say you're playing heads or tails ; you win 1\$ if you hit heads, you lose 1\$ if you hit tails. Then for any fixed $n$, the expected value of your overall gain after $n$ casts is 0\$, obviously. But if you have infinite amount of money, and you decide to keep playing until your overall gain is 10\$, then almost surely you will finally hit that "10\$ time", take the cash and walk away. Hence the expected value of your gain is 10\$.

Comment: Crystal clear! Now it makes sense more.